# strange data display in select at Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Already a dead hour I puzzle over a problem with.

Why in the first case is `SECURITY_WITHOUT` displayed, and in the second - `display`? After all, everything is identical ...

In general, in both cases, the translated phrase with `django.po` should be displayed. But how to achieve this? ...

**models.py**

```
CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT = 'display1'
CONFIRMATION_WITH = 'display2'                 #`display2` showed

CONFIRMATION_CHOICES = (
    (CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT, _('Display1')),
    (CONFIRMATION_WITH, _('Display2')),
)

SECURITY_WITHOUT = 'Display1'
SECURITY_WITH = 'Display2'                      #`SECURITY_WITH` showed

SECURITY_CHOICES = (
    ('SECURITY_WITHOUT', _('Display1')),
    ('SECURITY_WITH', _('Display2')),
)

income_proof = models.CharField(_('proof'), max_length=255, choices=CONFIRMATION_CHOICES, default=CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT)
security = models.CharField(_('security'), max_length=255, choices=SECURITY_CHOICES, default=SECURITY_WITHOUT)
```

**forms.py**

```
security = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CreditPayment.objects.values_list('security', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "selectpicker form-control", 'title':_("Security")}))
income_proof = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CreditPayment.objects.values_list('income_proof', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker form-control', 'title':_("Income proof")}))
```

**template**

```
{{ big_form.security }}
{{ big_form.income_proof }}
```

**html**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control show">
  <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="id_big-security" name="big-security" tabindex="-98">
   <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
   <option value="SECURITY_WITHOUT">SECURITY_WITHOUT</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="id_big-security" title="---------" aria-expanded="true"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">---------</div></div> </div></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu show" role="combobox" style="max-height: 394px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 61px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;" x-placement="bottom-start"><div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="-1" style="max-height: 376px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner show"><li class="selected active"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item selected active" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true"><span class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span class="text">---------</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><span class=" bs-ok-default check-mark"></span><span class="text">SECURITY_WITHOUT</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control">
  <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="id_big-income_proof" name="big-income_proof" tabindex="-98">
   <option class="bs-title-option" value=""></option>
   <option value="display">display</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="id_big-income_proof"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner"></div></div> </div></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu " role="combobox"><div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner show"></ul></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update SECURITY_CHOICES with this.

```
SECURITY_CHOICES = (
    (SECURITY_WITHOUT, _('Without display')),  #The Without display translated phrase should be displayed (from django.po).
)
```

As mentioned in the other answer from Daniel you've missed out a comma that is turning a single item into a tuple. I just added the example for clarity

Answer (score 1):

They're *not* the same. CONFIRMATION_CHOICES is a tuple of tuples; its single element is followed by a comma. SECURITY_CHOICES is a single tuple, since its element is not followed by a comma.

The choices value needs to be a tuple of tuples, which is why it works in the first case but not in the second. Add the missing comma after the close parenthesis.